# Jacobi-update: Crash when using Tango.getCameraIntrinsics

Tags: google-project-tango

Before the Jacobi update I was getting the camera intrinsics this way with no issue:

```
TangoCameraIntrinsics t = mTango.getCameraIntrinsics(1);
```

After the Jacobi update I try to get the camera intrinsics by calling the same function this way:

```
TangoCameraIntrinsics t = mTango.getCameraIntrinsics(TangoCameraIntrinsics.TANGO_CAMERA_COLOR);
```

calling the function in the Jacobi release now generates this crash while running the app:

```
A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64] JNI DETECTED ERROR IN APPLICATION: native code passing in reference to invalid stack indirect reference table or invalid reference: 0x649259b8
A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]     in call to DeleteLocalRef
A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]     from int com.google.atap.tango.TangoJNINative.GetCameraIntrinsics(int, com.google.atap.tangoservice.TangoCameraIntrinsics)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64] "main" prio=5 tid=1 Runnable
A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   | group="main" sCount=0 dsCount=0 obj=0x646d0b70 self=0x41756ea8
A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   | sysTid=7203 nice=0 cgrp=apps sched=0/0 handle=0x400a9154
A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   | state=R schedstat=( 1271432728 1183033922 4621 ) utm=85 stm=41 core=1 HZ=100
A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   | stack=0xbe325000-0xbe329000 stackSize=8MB
A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   native: art::Thread::DumpStack(std::ostream&) const+87 [0x416a4b78] (libart.so)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   native: ??? [0x415508a6] (libart.so)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   native: art::JniAbortF(char const*, char const*, ...)+51 [0x41551254] (libart.so)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   native: ??? [0x41553980] (libart.so)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   native: ??? [0x41554806] (libart.so)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   native: ??? [0x41555d3a] (libart.so)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   native: Java_com_google_atap_tango_TangoJNINative_GetCameraIntrinsics+475 [0x4ad6e36c] (libtango_client_api.so)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   at com.google.atap.tango.TangoJNINative.GetCameraIntrinsics(Native method)
A/art﹕ art/runtime/check_jni.cc:64]   at com.google.atap.tangoservice.Tango.getCameraIntrinsics(Tango.java:318)
```

Any ideas on how to fix this problem?

Comment: This looks like a bug with the new library. Thanks for reporting this, will update as we fix this issue.

Comment: hi, this issue is fixed and next release(L) should have this function working normally.

Comment: @r4ravi2008 I get the same crash with my NDK module (not Project Tango related). Do you have a link to the commit that fixed the crash?

Comment: Just download the latest Project Tango java library from [Downloads](https://developers.google.com/project-tango/downloads) page

Comment: @r4ravi2008 my project has nothing to do with Tango, I just have the same crash on my app that uses the NDK. I'm looking for pointers of what could cause the problem.